# Temporal Aggregation in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, aggregation, temporal-database

I am working on a Java implementation for temporal aggregation using a PostgreSQL database.

My table looks like this

```
Value | Start      | Stop
(int) | (Date)     | (Date)
-------------------------------
1     | 2004-01-01 | 2010-01-01
4     | 2000-01-01 | 2008-01-01
```

So to visualize this periods:

```
                      ------------------------------
  ----------------------------------------
2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010
  [        4         ][       5=4+1      ][    1   ]
```

My algorithm now calculates temporal aggregations of the data, e.g. SUM():

```
Value | Start      | Stop
-------------------------------
4     | 2000-01-01 | 2004-01-01
5     | 2004-01-01 | 2008-01-01
1     | 2008-01-01 | 2010-01-01
```

In order to test the gained results, I now would like to query the data directly using PostgreSQL. I know that there is no easy way to this problem, yet. However, there surely is a way to get the same results. The aggregations Count, Max, Min, Sum and Average should be supported. I do not mind a bad or slow solution, it just has to work.

A query I found so far which should work similarly is the following:

```
select count(*), ts, te
from ( checkout a normalize checkout b using() ) checkoutNorm
group by ts, te;
```

My adoption looks like this:

```
select count(*), start, stop
from ( myTable a normalize myTable b using() ) myTableNorm
group by start, stop;
```

However, an error was reported `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "normalize" -- LINE 2: from ( ndbs_10 a normalize ndbs_10 b using() ) ndbsNorm`.

Does anyone has a solution to this problem? It does not have to be based on the above query, as long as it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your calculation doesn't make sense to me. I don't see any logical way to derive {4, 2000-01-01, 2004-01-01} from {1, 2004-01-01, 2010-01-01} and {4, 2000-01-01, 2008-01-01}. I must be missing something.

Comment: That means that in the period from 2000 to 2004 (not including) the SUM(value) was 4. The period from 2004 to 2008 (not including) was overlapped by two periods, so their values should be summed up. Does it make sense now?

Comment: What in particular does not make sense to you? Think of a table containing the salaries of workers (one per row) and the periods they were employed. The result now should be the total paid salary per period (or max, min, average, count).

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL, and which temporal module?

Comment: It is PostgreSQL 8.4.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc-4.4.real (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5, 64-bit with no known temporal additions. This runs on a server I can not update, but I could use a local database instead.

Comment: Where did the syntax `from ... normalize ... using()` come from?

Comment: Does your original table allow (have) overlapping intervals (per id, I presume) ? If so: what do they mean?

Comment: If the intervals overlap, you want to _sum_ the values?

Comment: @Catcall That was a solution from an older lecture I visited.

Comment: @wildplasser Yes exactly. See the answer for another possible result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question was really hard to understand. But I *think* I figured it out.
You want a running sum over `value`. Values are only applicable between `start` and `stop` of a time period. So they have to be added at the begin of that period and deducted at the end.
In addition you want the begin and end of the resulting period the sum is valid for.
That should do it:

```
-- DROP SCHEMA x CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA x;
CREATE TABLE x.tbl(val int, start date, stop date);
INSERT INTO x.tbl VALUES
 (4 ,'2000-01-01' ,'2008-01-01')
,(7 ,'2001-01-01' ,'2009-01-01')
,(1 ,'2004-01-01' ,'2010-01-01')
,(2 ,'2005-01-01' ,'2006-01-01');

WITH a AS (
    SELECT start as ts, val FROM x.tbl
    UNION  ALL
    SELECT stop, val * (-1) FROM x.tbl
    ORDER  BY 1, 2)
SELECT sum(val) OVER w AS val_sum
      ,ts AS start
      ,lead(ts) OVER w AS stop
FROM   a
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY ts)
ORDER  BY ts;

val_sum |   start    |    stop
--------+------------+------------
      4 | 2000-01-01 | 2001-01-01
     11 | 2001-01-01 | 2004-01-01
     12 | 2004-01-01 | 2005-01-01
     14 | 2005-01-01 | 2006-01-01
     12 | 2006-01-01 | 2008-01-01
      8 | 2008-01-01 | 2009-01-01
      1 | 2009-01-01 | 2010-01-01
      0 | 2010-01-01 |
```

#### Edit after request

For all requested aggregate functions:

```
SELECT period
      ,val_sum
      ,val_count
      ,val_sum::float /val_count AS val_avg
      ,(SELECT min(val) FROM x.tbl WHERE start < y.stop AND stop > y.start) AS val_min
      ,(SELECT max(val) FROM x.tbl WHERE start < y.stop AND stop > y.start) AS val_max
      ,start
      ,stop
FROM   (
    WITH a AS (
         SELECT start as ts, val, 1 AS c FROM x.tbl
         UNION  ALL
         SELECT stop, val, -1 FROM x.tbl
         ORDER  BY 1, 2)
    SELECT count(*) OVER w AS period
          ,sum(val*c) OVER w AS val_sum
          ,sum(c) OVER w AS val_count
          ,ts AS start
          ,lead(ts) OVER w AS stop
    FROM   a
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY ts)
    ORDER  BY ts
    ) y
WHERE stop IS NOT NULL;

 period | val_sum | val_count | val_avg | val_min | val_max |   start    |    stop
--------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+------------+------------
      1 |       4 |         1 |       4 |       4 |       4 | 2000-01-01 | 2001-01-01
      2 |      11 |         2 |     5.5 |       4 |       7 | 2001-01-01 | 2004-01-01
      3 |      12 |         3 |       4 |       1 |       7 | 2004-01-01 | 2005-01-01
      4 |      14 |         4 |     3.5 |       1 |       7 | 2005-01-01 | 2006-01-01
      5 |      12 |         3 |       4 |       1 |       7 | 2006-01-01 | 2008-01-01
      6 |       8 |         2 |       4 |       1 |       7 | 2008-01-01 | 2009-01-01
      7 |       1 |         1 |       1 |       1 |       1 | 2009-01-01 | 2010-01-01
```

`min()` and `max` could possibly be optimized, but that should be good enough.
CTE (`WITH` clause) and and subqueries are exchangeable, as you can see.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to ask a hardly understandable question. Thank you very much for your answer. It works for SUM(). How can I make it work with min, max, avg and count?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: excellent trick, differentiating. I was just about to create some awesome rules and combine them with a recursive CTE... at str: your question is still badly phrased. If you want an AVG, does that mean you want to respect _all_ the boundaries from all the intervals currently present?

Comment: @str: I amended my answer with a fully featured query.

Comment: @wildplasser: sorry to have voided your efforts, but once I saw what str wanted I had to go for it. It's a kind of an addiction.

Comment: It could never have supported the additional aggregates anyway. But wanting to normalise date intervals is a disease as well, you know... Excellent solution.

Comment: @str: there was a glitch with the boundaries for min / max. See amended version.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. I really appreciate your help :) Sorry, to all that the question was not clear.